# Clicking on radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine, protractor

I have following rendered HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-8 no-padding">
    <label class="radio-inline gender-label">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male-signup" value="MALE" ng-model="signup.gender" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
        <label for="male-signup">Male</label>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline gender-label">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female-signup" value="FEMALE" ng-model="signup.gender" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
        <label for="female-signup">Female</label>
    </label>
</div>
```

So, to select Male radio button I did the following

```
element(by.id('male-signup')).click();
```

It complained `Element not visible`

Then i did

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var gender = element(by.id('male-signup'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(gender), 5000);
gender.click();
```

It complained `Failed: Wait timed out after 5005ms`

What is wrong with code?
I simply want to click on Gender male radio button

**Update:**

As per one of the answer below from 'Ernst Zwingli' I tried following. However, It still complains `Failed: Wait timed out after 5005ms`

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var gender = element(by.id('male-signup')).element(by.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[8]/div[2]/label[1]/label'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(gender), 5000);
gender.click();
```

Comment: If there is no trigger on the selection, you can simply set the value. If there is a trigger, maybe you should give us that code too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably can also click the label to select the radio-button, the element, which is to be clicked effectively might be its parent.

Try this:

```
//select your element, then go to its parent-element.
element(by.id('male-signup')).element(by.xpath('..')).click();
```

Or with your wait-statement:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
//this selects the <label class="radio-inline gender-label"> above "male-signup"
//potentially the parent-element is visible instead of the id-element
var gender = element(by.id('male-signup')).element(by.xpath('..'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(gender), 5000);
gender.click();
```

And here is your HTML-Page as snippet, where you see, that clicking the label also works.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="col-xs-8 no-padding">
      <label class="radio-inline gender-label">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male-signup" value="MALE" ng-model="signup.gender" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
          <label for="male-signup">Male</label>
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline gender-label">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female-signup" value="FEMALE" ng-model="signup.gender" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
          <label for="female-signup">Female</label>
      </label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your way but it still gives timeout error. Please see my update section under my question

Comment: That was not, what I suggested. My suggestion was to first select the element as you do, and then from there go one level up to its parent-element. Your code now just accesses the label-tag below the same parent as the selected element, so your code does this: `element(by.id('male-signup')).element(by.xpath('../label')).click();`

Comment: Sorry i am confused. If you can update your answer that would be great help for me to understand your point. thanks

Comment: updated and wrote the code part now including your browser.wait() function

Comment: Your updated answer is exactly same what i wrote under my question update. I don't see any difference. Can you recheck line by line and tell me which line has difference?

Comment: from your xpath-statement the very last "label" is too much: `by.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[8]/div[2]/label[1]/label'))` <> `by.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[8]/div[2]/label[1]'))`

Comment: Excellent. It works now. But please tell me what difference it create by removing '/label' from my xpath? I see your xpath and my xpath has difference of '/label'. I removed it and it works fine.

Comment: In short: I'm accessing the element <label class="radio-inline gender-label"> and you're accessing the element <label for="male-signup">. With `element(by.xpath('..'))` you're moving from the selected element <input id="male-signup"> to its parent-element <label class="radio-inline gender-label">. But as the parent-elements don't differ between Male and Female, one must first select the child-element and then go one step up to its parent element (going up to its parent is best reached `by.xpath('..')`). If I could help it will be nice, when you mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `timeout error` .

Delete `setTimeout 10000` until `setTimeout 35000` If you dont need it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var gender = element(by.id('male-signup')).element(by.xpath('//*[@id="top"]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[8]/div[2]/label[1]/label'));
    setTimeout(gender, 2000);
    setTimeout(gender, 5000);
    setTimeout(gender, 10000);
    setTimeout(gender, 15000);
    setTimeout(gender, 20000);
    setTimeout(gender, 25000);
    setTimeout(gender, 30000);
    setTimeout(gender, 35000);
gender.click();

})
```